# Facebook: how to selectively make status updates visible only to certain groups?

Tags: facebook, privacy

My friends list has people from work and my real friends.  By default, I want my status updates to be visible only to my friends.  And sometimes I want may want my updates to be visible to everyone.  What are my options in setting something like this up?

Comment: I used to be able to do this with the old profile. Since Facebook upgraded me to the new profile I cannot select friend lists in the privacy settings or even below single posts anymore although the lists all still exist and older posts/settings have not been effected...

For now I can only type in single names of people I want to be able to see a certain post/link/photo or make it visible to everyone, which is extremely bothering...

I wrote to facebook a few days ago but have yet to get a response...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three easy steps:

1. Create two lists (Account > Edit Friends > Create a List): Real Friends and Co-workers; sort FB friends accordingly
2. Account > Privacy Settings > Customize Settings > Posts By Me > Customize >
   Under "Make this visible to" on the line labeled "These people:" select "Specific People..." and type the names of the lists or individuals
3. When posting status, click on the padlock icon to change visibility from the default you set above

**N.B.:** Lists are not the same as Groups. Lists are private and under your control -  nobody knows which of your lists they belong to nor can they remove themselves from your lists.

Comment: I created my Real Friends list.  But when I go to Account > Privacy Settings > Customize Settings > Posts By Me > Customize,  a "Custom Privacy" dialog box appears.  In this box, I don't see a way to select my "Real Friends" list.  Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Under "Make this visible to" on the line labeled "These people:" you select "Specific People..." and type the names of the lists or individuals.

Comment: Great! I updated my answer with those additional details.